# put two input text in the same line

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using html and jquery mobile.here is the code:

```
<div data-role = "content">
        <form action = "?" method="post" name="form" id = "form">
            <fieldset>
            <div data-role = "fieldcontain" class = "ui-hide-label">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>

            <div data-role ="fieldcontain" class= "ui-hide-label">
                <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="" placeholder="Surname"/>
            </div>

            <div data-role ="fieldcontain" class= "ui-hide-label">
                <label for="address">Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="" placeholder="Address"/>
            </div>


                <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                    <label for="birth-place">Birth Place</label>
                    <input type="text" name="birth-place" id="birth_place" value="" placeholder="Birth Place" />
                </div>
                <div data-role = "fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                    <label for="province">Province</label>
                    <input type="text" name="province" id="province" value="" placeholder="PR" />
                </div>


                <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                    <label for"date">Birth Date</label>
                    <input type="datetime" name="dt" id="dt" value="" placeholder="Birth Date" />
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="male" />
                        <label for="radio-choice-1">Male</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="female"  />
                        <label for="radio-choice-2">Female</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-type="horizontal">
                    <label for="select-choice-0"></label>
                    <select name="select" id="select">
                        <option value="politrauma">Politrauma</option>
                        <option value="cardiologico">Cardiologico</option>
                        <option value="neurologico">Neurologico</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I'm not able to put in the same line two input text. I tried block grid but it didn't work

Comment: You mean side by side? What have you tried so far? What goes wrong when you try?

Comment: And what is your CSS? You can use simple `float` to make them both in the same line.

Answer (score 7):

You should look at two column layout in jquerymobile:
[jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/content/content-grids.html](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/content/content-grids.html)

Your code should be something like this:

```
<form action = "./includes/user_form.php" method="post" id = "form">
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div data-role = "fieldcontain" class = "ui-hide-label ui-block-a">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
            <div data-role ="fieldcontain" class= "ui-hide-label ui-block-b">
                <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="" placeholder="Surname"/>
            </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Are ugly tables an option for you?

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is kind of old but I just had the same problem and this is what worked for me:

```
<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="ui-block-a">
        <input type="text" id="" name="" value="">
</div>
<div class="ui-block-b">
        <input type="text" id="" name="" value="">
</div>
```

You can even add some style to change the relative size of the field.

Answer (score 3):

Just add floats to the divs:

```
<form action = "./includes/user_form.php" method="post" id = "form">
        <div data-role = "fieldcontain" class = "ui-hide-label" style="float:left">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>
        <div data-role ="fieldcontain" class= "ui-hide-label" style="float:left">
            <label for="surname">Surname</label>
            <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="" placeholder="Surname"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: @ShadowWizard what you show on jsfiddle is wrong, you didn't load the jquery UI module!

Comment: @Luc right didn't notice that. [Still working though](http://jsfiddle.net/PDrEP/52/) with jQuery, jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile all loaded. Can you can please update the fiddle to a non working example?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `<span>` wrapper around input with class that overrides `display` attribute of nested `<div>` (generated by jquery mobile). Also you must explicitly set width of input.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/FabyD/

CSS:

```
.inlineinput div {
    display: inline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    some text
    <span class="inlineinput">
        <input type='text' style='display: inline; width: 50px;' />
    </span>
    some text
    <span class="inlineinput">
        <input type='text' style='display: inline; width: 50px;' />
    </span>
    some text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`DIV`s are block elements - by default they take up 100% width. This makes the following elements appear on "the next line".

So, you need to move the second set on elements into the same DIV as the first (or re-style your DIVs with a fixed-width and use floats, but that's a little more challenging)

Answer (score 0):

Another tip is checking out the data-type="horizontal" -type (no pun intended).

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                      <label for="textinput11">
                        Something:
                      </label>
                      <input name="something" id="textinput11" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                      <label for="textinput12">
                        Something else:
                      </label>
                      <input name="something_else" id="textinput12" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>
```